# Query two different models in a separate model Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to query information from two different models. I have 3 models, `Company`, `User` and `Employment`
Relationship between `User` and `Company` is many-to-many through `Employment`. Which means there's no `company_id` column in my `User` table, just on the `Employment` table.

```
Company.where(category: Company::FIRMS).where(company_tier_id: 1).includes(:directory_las, :directory_associates, :directory_lats).order(name: :asc)

has_many :directory_affiliates, -> { where(member_category_id: [5, 14]).order(:user_id)}, class_name: 'User'(this is run on the Company model)
```

This is the code I run on my view to trigger the above queries:

```
- if company.directory_affiliates.present?
        %h4.company-detail-heading Affiliates
        - company.directory_affiliates.each do |user|
          = user
          %br
```

The queries reproduce the following SQL queries:

```
Company Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."category" = $1 AND "companies"."company_tier_id" = $2 ORDER BY "companies"."name" ASC  [["category", "Landscape Architecture Firms"], ["company_tier_id", 1]]
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."member_category_id" IN (1, 2, 7, 8, 9, 15) AND "users"."company_id" IN (30, 211, 104, 88, 89, 135, 6, 32, 127, 13, 77, 268) ORDER BY "users"."first_name" ASC
```

How can I re-write the queries so that I can get the `company_id` to query from the `employments` table? I'll really appreciate any response.

Comment: `join` tables and you can filter data.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem was me using `include` istead of `joins` because of the change of associations. This worked perfectly:

```
Company.where(category: Company::FIRMS).where(company_tier_id: 1).joins(:directory_las, :directory_associates, :directory_lats).order(name: :asc)
```